# How to add newline after certain word without removing it using regex in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to add newline \n after a certain word without removing it

Example:

```
<Data Name='UserParameters'>-</Data><Data Name='SidHistory'>-</Data>
```

To be:

```
<Data Name='UserParameters'>-</Data>
<Data Name='SidHistory'>-</Data>
```

I tried to use replace `</Data>` with \n but it will remove  and replace it with newline.

Comment: *"I tried to use replace `</Data>` with `\n` but it will remove and replace it with newline."* -- It does what you ask it to do. You also said in the first sentence: *"I want to add newline"*. If you want to add something then add it to the search string, don't replace the search string with it. Replace `</Data>` with `</Data>\n` and don't forget to check the "Use Regular Expression" option (`.*`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how VSCode does this exactly, but from the information in your question you can try replacing `</Data>` with `</Data>\n` and it should work.

This means that wherever `</Data>` is detected, `</Data>\n` will replace it, in effect adding `\n` after it.